# Why does "imagex /apply" have to be run from Windows PE (but not really)?

Tags: windows, disk-image, deployment, imagex

Microsoft TechNet's [command-line reference for `imagex`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx) says of the `/apply` switch, and I quote:

> ⚠ **Important**
>   You must run this option from Windows PE.

Since I didn't care about silly things like breaking my Windows installation, I ran `imagex /apply` on an external drive **from Windows 8.1** anyway. Nothing bad happened (no errors), and it was successful - the WIM was indeed applied as I wanted.

My copy of `imagex` states that its version is `6.3.9600.17095`.

Why is that warning there? Is there a terrible "gotcha!" awaiting me in some special circumstance, or is the documentation just outdated/wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, the `/apply` option writes an image to a target disk. 
This operation is destructive, erasing whatever data is present on the disk, and writing the desired image over it.

Usually this option is performed for system preperation, by booting the system from a liveCD (in this case WindowsPE) and applying the image to the systems primary hard disk. This is not possible while the OS on the target disk is booted and active, in part because the processes that are writing the image rely on the booted OS to perform the writing. Its the same principal as deleting all the files on an OS partition while the OS is running. the result is almost invariably a broken system.

In this case, you targeted an external disk, and as a result, there is no risk of destroying the running OS while applying the image.

Comment: It works because it was an external disk.  If it was the system disk it would not have worked.

Comment: that is correct, because a system disk could not be 100% at rest. this is true whether you are reading or writing an image, but you are correct, my answer was orriented toward taking an image rather than writing one. answers still the same though. writing an image to an booted system would crash it part way through the write.

Comment: Then how does software like Acronis image a system drive while it is booted into it? I do this all the time and never had an issue restoring images and using them.

Comment: Acronis and Ghost are not just simple imagers; they integrate an awareness of the OS and the filesystem. As such their output is not an exact image of a disk at an precise instant in time. That makes them great for a lot of tasks that `dd` and other raw imagers are not, but also makes them far more complicated. For instance you would not want to use Acronis for Forsensic purposes; it would potentially corrupt the chain of evidence.

Comment: I'm not sure ImageX is a simple imager - the [WIM format](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096) definitely knows about files, directories, and security descriptors. And, just to be clear (the above comments are confusing the issue), it is the *volume* that matters, not the *disk*, right? I think (but am not sure - this was several months ago) that I successfully expanded a WIM onto a different partition on the same drive as the boot volume.